# Dynamic routing in bundle.js

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to dynamically load data into bundle.js in angular2. 
Is it possible? If yes then how and if not then is there any alternative to that. I want to make my routes secure so for that i need this that is dynamic loading of routes

Comment: you can lazy load your routes, compiler will break them into respective chunks. check the documentation https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.
But i have gone through that link and i think it packs all the modules in bundle and on demand loads one of the module.
My problem is that i don't want my bundle.js to have specific modules and they should be call on runtime i.e. dynamic loading of specific modules

Answer (score 0):

You can lazy load modules by defining your routes as follows

```
{
  path: 'lazyLoad',
  loadChildren: 'app/test.module#TestModule',
  canLoad: [AuthGuard]
}
```

the `canLoad` Guard controls whether it is loaded or not depending on the returned value from the `AuthGuard` service. All lazy loaded modules are bundled into separate chunks and loaded on the fly when that specific route is requested.

*Do not import lazy loaded module in you main app.module*

Please check the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router) for more information

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the question remains same that is if we make the code build ready we will get a dist folder in which bundle and all the lazy loading routes will also be available. So, by using inspect element we can still find all the routes.
Please correct me if i am wrong.
What i want is only one bundle should be there and the chunks must be available only on demand depending upon certain criteria like user role and permissions.